# text select when drag in javascript

Tags: javascript, select, drag-and-drop

When I make an element in the page draggable,and once I drag it,text outside this element will be selected.

I wonder why and how to prevent this?

Here is [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/eZV3T/):

When I drag the gray div and over the paragraphs as fast as possible,the text of the paragraphs will be selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to prevent the default behaviour

```
trigger.onmousedown = function(e) {
    this.style.cursor = "move";
    e.preventDefault(); // this line
    ...
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eZV3T/2/)

Comment: Thanks,it works. And it seems that I can also remove the code `trigger.onselectstart and trigger.ondragstart`,isn't it?

Comment: it seems that it does not support ie and chrome

Comment: yes IE does not suppert prevent default, the work around is to use jQuery or use the `window.event` object and set `window.event.returnValue = false`